# Kubernetes dashboard issue

Tags: kubernetes

Unable to access the Kubernetes dashboard. 
Executed below steps:

1. kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
2. kubectl proxy --address="192.168.56.12" -p 8001 --accept-hosts='^*$'
3. Now trying to access from url:
   http://192.168.56.12:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

````
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}```

Output of a few commands that will required:
````

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49-zn2c2 --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard

Error from server: Get https://192.168.56.14:10250/containerLogs/kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49-7wz6q/kubernetes-dashboard: dial tcp 192.168.56.14:10250: connect: no route to host
[root@k8s-master ~]#

```
$kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE      
ATES
kube-system            coredns-5c98db65d4-89c9p                    1/1     Running            0          76m   10.244.0.14     k8s-master
kube-system            coredns-5c98db65d4-ggqfj                    1/1     Running            0          76m   10.244.0.13     k8s-master
kube-system            etcd-k8s-master                             1/1     Running            0          75m   192.168.56.12   k8s-master
kube-system            kube-apiserver-k8s-master                   1/1     Running            0          75m   192.168.56.12   k8s-master
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-k8s-master          1/1     Running            1          75m   192.168.56.12   k8s-master
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-amd64-74zrn                 1/1     Running            1          74m   192.168.56.14   node1     
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hgcp8                 1/1     Running            0          75m   192.168.56.12   k8s-master
kube-system            kube-proxy-2lczb                            1/1     Running            0          74m   192.168.56.14   node1     
kube-system            kube-proxy-8dxdm                            1/1     Running            0          76m   192.168.56.12   k8s-master
kube-system            kube-scheduler-k8s-master                   1/1     Running            1          75m   192.168.56.12   k8s-master
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-fb986f88d-d49sw   1/1     Running            0          71m   10.244.1.21     node1     
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49-7wz6q       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   18         71m   10.244.1.20     node1     

=========================================

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49-7wz6q -n kubernetes-dashboard
Name:           kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49-7wz6q
Namespace:      kubernetes-dashboard
Priority:       0
Node:           node1/192.168.56.14
Start Time:     Mon, 23 Sep 2019 12:56:18 +0530
Labels:         k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
                pod-template-hash=6bb65fcc49
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.244.1.20
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49
Containers:
  kubernetes-dashboard:
    Container ID:  docker://2cbbbc9b95a43a5242abe13f8178dc589487abcfccaea06ff4be70781f4c3711
    Image:         kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0-beta4
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard@sha256:a35498beec44376efcf8c4478eebceb57ec3ba39a6579222358a1ebe455ec49e
    Port:          8443/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --auto-generate-certificates
      --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Mon, 23 Sep 2019 14:10:27 +0530
      Finished:     Mon, 23 Sep 2019 14:10:28 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  19
    Liveness:       http-get https://:8443/ delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /certs from kubernetes-dashboard-certs (rw)
      /tmp from tmp-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kubernetes-dashboard-token-q7j4z (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kubernetes-dashboard-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kubernetes-dashboard-certs
    Optional:    false
  tmp-volume:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kubernetes-dashboard-token-q7j4z:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kubernetes-dashboard-token-q7j4z
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                        From            Message
  ----     ------   ----                       ----            -------
  Warning  BackOff  <invalid> (x354 over 63m)  kubelet, node1  Back-off restarting failed container
[root@k8s-master ~]#
```

Comment: As i can see you have installed 3 flannels and weave-net on your kubernetes cluster, first of all i would recommend to delete all of them and create 1 instead.

Additionally please provide a screen after using this command: `kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49-zn2c2 -n kubernetes-dashboard`

Comment: jt97 they are deamonsets. Which means there are 3 nodes.

Comment: @jt97- pasted the output of kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard and kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces

Comment: @muku Please provide me 1 more thing, logs.
Use this command `kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49-7wz6q -n kubernetes-dashboard`

Comment: @jt97 its the same error: Error from server: Get https://192.168.56.14:10250/containerLogs/kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-6bb65fcc49-7wz6q/kubernetes-dashboard: dial tcp 192.168.56.14:10250: connect: no route to host

Comment: @muku Can you use 'kubectl version' and tell me which version you use?
Meaby there are some problems with compatibility.
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases

Comment: @jt97 [root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:13:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.4", GitCommit:"67d2fcf276fcd9cf743ad4be9a9ef5828adc082f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:41:55Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
[root@k8s-master ~]#

Comment: @muku Ok, have u tried to reinstall dashboard? If not, try to delete it with those commands `kubectl delete deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard kubectl delete service kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard kubectl delete sa kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard kubectl delete secret kubernetes-dashboard-certs --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard kubectl delete secret kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard` and install it from [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) and let me know if it's working.

Comment: @jt97 yes,i have already tried deleting and reinstalling but always stuck at same issue.

Comment: Let's go further, show me kubelet status using `sudo systemctl status kubelet`, show me your services and endpoints using 
`kubectl get svc,ep --all-namespaces`,check if [dns pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-if-the-dns-pod-is-running) is running.

Answer (score 1):

After realizing that the chart `stable/kubernetes-dashboard` is outdated, I found that you need to apply this manifest  :

```sh
kubectl apply -f \
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

However, this is not acceptable to migrate from helm chart to hard coded manifests..
After some search, the related chart is now [under this Git repo subfolder](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/aio/deploy/helm-chart/kubernetes-dashboard)
No more `stable` repo, but use the following:

```sh
helm repository add kubernetes-dashboard https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/
helm install kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard --name my-release
```

Good luck! This will fix all your issues since this chart considers all dependencies.

By the way:

- even the image repository is no more `k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64`
  Instead, it is now under dockerhub `kubernetesui/dashboard`
- There is a sidecar for metrics **scraper** which not defined in the  stable chart.